# Eigenfunctions of Laplace-Beltrami operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and 
$$Lf:=-\operatorname{div} \nabla(f)$$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Let $f$ be a smooth function on $M$. Consider the optimization problem of minimizing

$$\int_ML(f)f$$

under the constraint $\int_M |f|^2=1$. I wonder how to prove that if $f$ minimize the integral $\int_ML(f)f$, then it must be an eigenfunction of $L$, i.e. $L(f)=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda$.

I know it can be shown that $\int_M\|\nabla f\|^2= \int_ML(f)f$ but this may not be helpful.

Comment: Page 25 of this article http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/voli/2/nica.pdf solves a very similar problem via Lagrange multipliers

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$
\int_M L(f)f=\lVert\nabla f\rVert^2_{L^2(M)}\geq 0
$$
with equality if and only if $\nabla f=0$ almost everywhere.  So any smooth minimizer $f$ has zero derivative everywhere, hence locally constant.  But such functions are eigenfunctions of $L$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Thanks... although what I wanted to ask was the local minima... calculus of variations stuff

Comment: There are no local minima (only global minima), because this is a positive semidefinite quadratic.